# Whatsapp Cloud API - An unknown error occurred

Tags: facebook-graph-api, whatsapp

I recently started using the new Whatsapp Cloud API. Unfortunately already the sample request in the first steps guide gives an error message. The request to the `messages` endpoint gives the following response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "An unknown error occurred",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 1,
    "error_subcode": 2593006,
    "is_transient": false,
    "error_user_title": "Account Not Exist",
    "error_user_msg": "Account does not exist in Facebook Hosted API, please use /register API to create an account first.",
    "fbtrace_id": "AX1Thf9OPBhmj7NlDV6-5IA
"
  }
}
```

I am still using the Test WhatsApp Business Account with a Test Number.
When calling the register endpoint I get `You can’t complete the setup process because your business doesn’t meet WhatsApp’s policy requirements. If you think this is incorrect, reach out to Meta Business Suite support for help`.

Does anyone have an idea, what the problem is?

Thank you in advance,

Sören

Comment: There is a [thread](https://developers.facebook.com/community/threads/1928168504042050/) in FB community, and a [bug](https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/558663849219973/), you can follow.

Answer (score 0):

Whatapp Business Platform requires a verified FaceBook business account and also a working payment method. I recommend to verify your Facebook (Meta) Business Account.

Answer (score 0):

From your snippet, you are getting an OAuthException error meaning you do not have the correct authorization to perform that request, make sure that your access token in your 'Authorization' header field is the same as on your whatsapp business platfrom test account under 'Getting Started' and is up to date. See the following link - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/guides/error-handling/

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the use case, but if meta think you are violating their business terms of service they will disable the account. It doesn't matter if you are or not, it is if they think you are. In my experience this is if people receiving WA messages are blocking or reporting, even if they opted in. However I am not sure if there are various other circumstances meta may arrive at the same conclusion. I believe they have multiple automated processes checking and if these flag up then you are blocked. You can request a review, but these are also automated sometimes, so that may be an instant negative